# Is there any simple API that returns a live stock chart given a stock tag

Tags: highcharts, stock

I am doing research on an API that I give a stock tag say "AAPL" it returns a live stock chart to my web site. I am using NodeJS for it. Does anyone know what are some resources for this?

Comment: Highcharts Stock is a chart library that allows you to display the APPL chart, but you'll need to supply your own data source. For further context, refer to the following docs and examples of how to work with it: https://www.highcharts.com/samples/highcharts/blog/annotations-aapl-iphone; https://www.highcharts.com/demo/highcharts/live-data; https://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/data-intro;